# Preventing scrolling on clicking an internal link

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, hashchange, internal-link

I have an internal link on my html page. Two things happen on clicking an internal link.

1. Page is scrolled (jumped) so that the target of the link is at the top of the page.
2. url reflects the internal link clicked by showing /abc/#...

I noticed that the order of these two steps is also the same. i.e. `hashchange` is fired after the scrolling has happened. I want to prevent the scrolling but allow `hashchange` to occur. If I write an `onclick`event to return false (i.e. block it) then even the `hashchange` event is not fired. Any suggestions how else it could be done?

Comment: Have you tried `location.href = '/abc/#'; return false;`?

Comment: I guess you're still trying...

Comment: solved it by removing the element with the id that it refers to. Couldn't find the element couldn't scroll to it. Actually this link was used to open a panel and we wanted to make the resulting url as bookmarkable. i.e. if we had www.domain.org and a link <a href="#xyz">Show Panel with id xyz</a>, then this results in a url like www.domain.org#xyz which can be bookmarked. I simple removed the id xyz from the panel and hence panel is never scrolled to the top.  Thankx for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) or [`window.history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Those methods do not scroll. Sadly, Internet Explorer supports `history` only since version 10.

Example:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(oEvent)
{
    if (oEvent.target.nodeName == 'A'
    &&  oEvent.target.hasAttribute('href')
    &&  oEvent.target.getAttribute('href').charAt(0) == '#')
    {
        oEvent.preventDefault();
        history.pushState(null, '', oEvent.target.getAttribute('href'));
    }
}, false);
```

PS. My page should keep working with scripts disabled, so I keep element's ID, at least until some link was clicked.